# Accessible Log file in App Data

Tags: java, android

I have created a logFile in my app as a way of tracking certain errors or messages that go on during the users experience. This is something for test purposes and I will be giving the app to test between a small number of developers. I want to, after some time, get the phones back and go in to retrieve these log files

The issue I am having is finding a way to access the app data from a computer (not using eclipse). Is there a way to make my app accessible to take files from any computer?

My file is created like so:

```
public void appendLog(String text) {
    File logFile = new File(mLogin.getFilesDir(),"logFile.txt");
    if (!logFile.exists()){
        try{
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
        //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `getFilesDir()` returns `/data/data/com.*****/files`. Is there a way to access this directory by plugging in the phone? Or is there another way to get the log file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.*****/files
```

I'm sure the folder /data/data is readable in a no root device, in this case, you have to move your file in the /sdcard/ folder.

Comment: When I run that code it just says 0 files pulled. 0 files skipped. I checked that the file was there and it is. I can read from it in the app